# Even and Odd numbers sorting into Text file

Tags: php

HI Everyone I need help in sorting out even and odd numbers. The numbers are entered in a form and are called to the php file ( at bottom) after which I need to display them in a text file this part for me is all good. I am having trouble separating the numbers even from odd. I know we need to use the modulus command but I don't know exactly how to place it in the loop.

```
    $valOne = $_GET["value1"];
    $valTwo = $_GET["value2"];
    $valThr = $_GET["value3"];
    $valFou = $_GET["value4"];
    $valFiv = $_GET["value5"];
    $valSix = $_GET["value6"];
    $valSev = $_GET["value7"];
    $valEig = $_GET["value8"];
    $valNine = $_GET["value9"];
    $valTen = $_GET["value10"];

    $myFile = "test.txt";
    $fh = fopen($myFile, 'w') or die("can't open file");
    $array1= array ($valOne, $valTwo, $valThr, $valFou,$valFiv,
                $valSix,$valSev,$valEig,$valNine,$valTen);
    foreach($array1 as $key => $value){
    fwrite($fh, $value. "\t");


    }
    fclose($fh);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what you want is

```
if ($number % 2 == 0) {
    // even number
}
else
{
    // odd
}
```

in your case

```
foreach($array1 as $key => $value){
    if ($value % 2 == 0) {
         fwrite($fh, $value. "\t");
    }
}
```

seperate even and odd numbers in one file

```
$even = array_filter($array1, function($number) { return $number % 2 == 0; });
$odd = array_filter($array1, function($number) { return $number % 2 == 1; });

$max = max(count($even), count($odd));
for ($i = 0; $i < $max; $i++) {
    $n1 = isset($even[$i]) ? $even[$i] : "";
    $n2 = isset($odd[$i]) ? $odd[$i] : "";

    fwrite($fh, str_pad($n1, 20, STR_PAD_RIGHT) . $n2);
}
```

Comment: yea but do I place it just below the foreach loop ? because I tried placing it earlier there it didnt work.

Comment: Inside the foreach? I think you would filter all even numbers from the array, so you have to check each number

Comment: OK thank you very much sir.I can work with this now...one more question if I wanted to separate the output like put all even on one side and odd on the other is that possible?

Comment: what do you mean with seperate? two files? in this case, you just have to open two file streams and write the even numbers to the even file stream and the other numbers to the odd file stream

Comment: two files is another way i was wondering if it was possible in the same file to have maybe two columns on one side even and the other odd.

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach($array1 as $key => $value)
{
   $myvar = ($value %2 == 0 ? '$value' : '' );
   fwrite($fh, $myvar . "\t");
}
```

Comment: your code is wrong. This `echo $myvar = ($value %2 == 0 ? '$value' : '' );` should not have `echo`. The `$value`, should not be in single quotes.

Answer (score 0):

try the following

```
 $valOne = $_GET["value1"];
$valTwo = $_GET["value2"];
$valThr = $_GET["value3"];
$valFou = $_GET["value4"];
$valFiv = $_GET["value5"];
$valSix = $_GET["value6"];
$valSev = $_GET["value7"];
$valEig = $_GET["value8"];
$valNine = $_GET["value9"];
$valTen = $_GET["value10"];

$myFile = "test.txt";
$fh = fopen($myFile, 'w') or die("can't open file");
$array1= array ($valOne, $valTwo, $valThr, $valFou,$valFiv,
            $valSix,$valSev,$valEig,$valNine,$valTen);
foreach($array1 as $key => $value){
  if($value%2==0)
   {
     fwrite($fh, $value. "\t");
      }
    else
    {
      //write your own code..
       }

}
fclose($fh);
```